# Object has no attribute on a Textfield in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am getting a

```
 'Sponsor' object has no attribute 'adtag'
```

error, when I try to pull data from a foreign key field in Django.

When I try to pull CharField data from the same model, that works perfectly fine.

Here are my models:

```
class Sponsor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name of Sponsor", max_length=120, blank=False)
    ... 
    adtag = models.TextField(name="Ad Tag")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name des Betriebs", max_length=120, blank=False)
    sponsor = models.ForeignKey(Sponsor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am calling this by doing this:

```
merchant = Merchant.objects.filter(id=merchant)
```

and

```
print(merchant.sponsor.adtag)
```

And of course the data is filled in in the database + foreign key is associated.

Thanks for any recommendation.

Comment: Does it have, by any chance, a comma at the endo, so `adtag = models.TextField(...),`?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the name= option here is defining the field name in the database. So it was looking for "Ad Tag" als a column name, not adtag.